# Ajax call to Spring MVC Controler Bad request

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, spring-mvc

The relevant part in Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/makeTransfer", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String makeTransfer(Map<String, Object> model, @RequestParam int id,  @RequestParam int sum, @RequestParam int ownerAccount,  @RequestParam int ownerBalance, @RequestParam int receiverAccount){ ...}
```

The Ajax call(I'm trying to have everything Integer)

```
function transfer(obj, idd, ownerAcc, ownerbal){
    var receiverAccount = parseInt($(obj).parent().find('#recAcc_field').val());
    var sum = parseInt($(obj).parent().find('#sum_field').val());
    var updatedSum = ownerbalance - sum;
    var id = parseInt(idd);
    var ownerAccount = parseInt(ownerAcc);
    var ownerbalance = parseInt(ownerbal);
    alert(ownerbalance);
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "makeTransfer.html",
        data: ({id : id, sum : sum, ownerAccount : ownerAccount, ownerbalance : ownerbalance, receiverAccount : receiverAccount}),
        success : function(data) {
            if (data=="success") {$(obj).closest('tr').find('#accBalance').val(updatedSum)}
            else {alert("error!!")}
        }
    })
}
```

In my JSP I use onclick call that function:

```
Receiving Account: <input id="recAcc_field" type="text"> 
Sum: <input id = "sum_field" type="text" onblur="checkTransfer(this,${account.balance})">
<input id="transferButton" disabled type="submit" value="Transfer" onclick='transfer(this, ${personna.id}, ${account.accountId}, ${account.balance})'>
```

I have other Ajax calls to my controller and everything works great and to me this code seems very similar to code wrote before which works wonderfully. Every parameter of my javascript function should be Integer, but I "parseInt" them anyway. What does the .val() return? An Integer or a String?(I know JavaScript is not like Java, but just wondering).
The error I'm getting is: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)`
Please let me know if you need additional information :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look in Chrome Developer tools so you can see the exact POST request, but upon first glance it looks like the case doesn't match on your parameter:

```
@RequestParam int ownerBalance
```

vs

```
data: ({id : id, sum : sum, ownerAccount : ownerAccount, ownerbalance : ownerbalance, receiverAccount : receiverAccount}),
enter code here
```

in your request. You can also mark all your `RequestParam`s as not required temporarily and see if that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much @david ! :)